# How can I disable Caps Lock in a simple way under X11 when there is no key binding for it?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap, capslock

I routinely disable Caps Lock and the respective modifier with a script, using `xmodmap`.  That all works fine.

Sometimes, however, for some reason unknown, Caps Lock is active.  Having no key bound to `Caps_Lock` and no key bound to toggle the `Lock` modifier, I cannot switch Caps Lock off unless I reset the keymap, press the key, then re-map it to my desired configuration.

So: **How can I disable Caps Lock (currently active) without re-mapping keys and with no keys bound to do the job?**

Perhaps a command line tool can set the state?

For anyone interested, here is how my script disables the accidental activation of Caps Lock by a key press (I never enable it intentionally):

```
#!/bin/sh
# I never want to use Caps_Lock.  Make Caps_Lock another Control_L...
xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Caps_Lock" 2> /dev/null
xmodmap -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L" 2> /dev/null
xmodmap -e "add Control = Control_L" 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any utility which does that (except maybe `xdotool key Caps_Lock`?), but in the meanwhile you can compile this little program with `cc xkb_unlock.c -s -lX11 -o ./xkb_unlock` (provided that you have installed a compiler and the libc & xorg development packages)
and use it as simply `./xkb_unlock`.

#### `xkb_unlock.c`

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/XKBlib.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
        Display *dpy;
        if(!(dpy = XOpenDisplay(0)))
                errx(1, "cannot open display '%s'", XDisplayName(0));
        XkbLockModifiers(dpy, XkbUseCoreKbd, 0xff, 0);
        XSync(dpy, False);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm, thanks!  BTW what is the `-s` option? Didn't find documentation with my GNU cc, worked without it.

Comment: `-s` strips the debug symbols, makes the (on-disk) binary smaller

Comment: Thanks. I normally use the `strip` command for that. Good to know, though.  At less than 21k size it's not a big concern in this case, though. BTW feel free to upvote my question if it was clear :-)

Comment: I cannot believe how much manpower has been wasted over the years because of this historic glitch of having this key in the firstplace (typewriters). 
We should vote it out of our computers. The few people still wanting to use that are for sure a tiny group against the people annoyed or unbothered.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work for me - simply doesn't do anything. Also "xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'" which worked for years stopped working. So probably something changed in X11 recently, but I still have no idea what :-(

Comment: @Nadav That program doesn't disable the CapsLock *key*, but turns the CapsLock *state* off when there's no CapsLock key you can use for that. As requested by the question. (In fact, it will unlock all modifiers, not just `LockMask`, but I don't know of any AltsLock key ;-)). Neither `setxkbmap` nor `xmodmap` can do that; `xdotool key Caps_Lock` can do that, but it will toggle the state, not turn it off.

Comment: Nice, sorry, I guess I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score -1):

For many years, `xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'` worked well for disabling the effect of caps lock. The xkb_unlock.c code posted in another answer does a similar things. But sadly, on my modern Linux distribution this no longer works. You need to use `setxkbmap`, instead of `xmodmap`:

```
setxkbmap -option caps:none
```

works like a charm.

Comment: Your suggestion removes the possibility to toggle `Caps Lock`. The question was about switching off `Caps Lock` while it is active and there is no key mapped to toggle/switch it. So basically, switch `Caps Lock` on, run your command, now how do you get rid of it (switch it off)?